# Convert SP2013 Windows Claims to ADFS Claims

Tags: powershell, error, authentication, adfs, claims

I used the below Microsoft PowerShell script to convert from SP2013 Windows Claims to ADFS Claims: Reference - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn744263.aspx

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "https://WebAppURL"

$tp= Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "ADFS Claims"

$skiplist = "D:\skiplist.csv"

Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity $wa -TO CLAIMS-TRUSTED-DEFAULT -FROM CLAIMS-WINDOWS -TrustedProvider $tp -sourceskiplist $skiplist -RetainPermissions -Force
```

But the script is displaying the below error:

> Convert-SPWebApplication : Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was
>   thrown.Parameter name: configuration

How do I fix this and convert the user to ADFS claims?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219696.aspx) documentation, in your code it appears you've used `-TrustedProvider` and `-sourceskiplist` as parameters, which do not appear in the MSDN doc.

Comment: the article you shared describes about converting from windows classic to windows claims

Comment: The article is the documentation for the cmdlet, the example it uses is converting windows classic to windows claims.